# Creating confirmation link for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Sometimes our users' confirmation emails get hung up, and I need to generate a confirmation link to send to them manually. I grabbed the code from Devise's mail view, but the link it generates is not the same that gets generated by the auto-generated confirmation email:

Code from Devise's confirmation mailer view:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %></p>
```

Example confirmation link:
**`http://myapp.com/confirmation?confirmation_token=dTDYagcDbfJehEJPThRi`**

Code I'm using in custom confirmation link generator:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@user, :confirmation_token => @user.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

Example confirmation link (Different from above- doesn't work):
**`http://myapp.com/confirmation?confirmation_token=162baabc80329f01209297af8c49a42e1fdf9066ffef412322b509bc5967052d`**

How can I generate a Devise confirmation link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because devise relatively recently (3.1+ I think?) increased security by encrypting tokens (including the confirmation token) before storing them in the database.  So the second long token is the encrypted version of the first, shorter token and therefore won't work.  The only place the confirmation token exists in unencrypted form is in the original email sent to the user.

This means that a new token needs to be generated each time a confirmation email is sent for a user.  Devise can allow users to request another confirmation email (`ConfirmationsController`) - have you disabled that?  It calls the `send_confirmation_instructions` *class* method on your user class (which is in devise's Confirmable module and in turn calls ends up calling `resend_confirmation_instructions`, which calls the `send_confirmation_instructions` *instance* method which can generate a new token).  You could probably call the `send_confirmation_instructions` *class* method on your user class yourself, but it would be easier to allow users to request another confirmation email themselves using the standard devise ConfirmationsController and routes/views.

Comment: @Tim- Thanks for the explanation. The problem is that occaisionally our users can't access auto-generated emails from our system (due to deliverability issues w certain ISPs), which means that no confirmation emails, whether automated or resent, can get through. In those cases we're looking for a way to generate a confirmation link ourselves and send it by alternate means. I'll look into the send_confirmation_instructions source and see if I can pick out a way to do that... will update...

Comment: Ah.  In that case generate_token in Confirmable is the thing that generates and saves a new confirmation token.  It leaves a @raw_confirmation_token in the instance, which is what is passed to the email template.  You might have some luck there.  Beware of possible interplay with reconfirmable (not sure though) if you have that enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative if you just want to **REDIRECT** the user **after clicking the confirmation**, just

**STEP 1** 
override the after_confirmation_path_for in your confirmations_controller:

Create a new confirmations_controller.rb in app/controllers directory:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  private
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
  your_new_after_confirmation_path
 end
end
```

**STEP 2** In config/routes.rb, add this line so that Devise will use your custom ConfirmationsController. This assumes Devise operates on users table (you may edit to match yours).

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations' }
```

**STEP 3** Restart the web server